# can wifi detect you even when you arn't detected

Tags: mac, spoofing

I've read that the way wifi works is that your computer sends out requests looking for any wifi it recognizes. I use a mac spoofer but if there is a wifi in range before i have time to spoof my mac address, will the wifi be able to see my mac address?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to Tor.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to the Information Security board: https://security.stackexchange.com/